# Make label only as wide as it needs to be?

Tags: ios, label

I have 3 labels next to each other inside a horizontal stack view like this

[image: stackview]

The first and last label are going to be dynamically filled with a word of variable length, while the middle one is always going to contain the word "with", for example: "Coding with Swift!"

I don't want there to be extra space between each word as it would look strange if the words are short. Is there any way to make the labels only be as wide as they need to be to fit their text? That way it all looks like one label (except I'm making the middle label have smaller text).

Comment: Isn't the storyboard's default UILabel behavior like that? You can use auto layout for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 3 labels inside a UIView instead of stack view.
And set constraints as shown in image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What distribution do I give the stack view?

Comment: Also, what if the first word is longer or shorter than "Coding", would it look funky?

Comment: I'm saying don't use stack view instead use UIView.
If coding is short text it will be adjusted accordingly. Edited answer.

Comment: Hey Amit, I ended up using a UIView, thanks much. Todah rabah!

Answer (score 1):

How about using autolayout?
You could give a horizontal space of 0 between the labels and a constraint of width for the middle one.

Answer (score 1):

If u wish to have different fonts for the content in a label you can use NSAttributedString

```
let boldFontDict:[String: AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: <UI Font>]

let 1stString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello")      
let 2ndString = NSAttributedString(string: "hii", attributes: boldFOntDict)

let finalAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: 1stString)

finalAttrStr.append(2ndString)

myLabel.attributedText = finalAttrStr
```

Comment: what about the alignment? The first string is left aligned, second one is centre while third one is right aligned. Could you post the solution implementing that?

Comment: It will be difficult to manage the width of 3 labels since the content is dynamic.

Comment: Instead you can align your `myLabel` as `centre aligned` and can give different font size to each `attributed string`

Comment: Yh would be a better to give different attributes and aligning the text content centre or left depending upon the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one label instead of taking three label 
and and set the text on label as

```
  label.text= firstLabel.text + "with" + lastLabel.text
```

Comment: but then can I made the word "with" be smaller than the rest of the text?

Comment: Yes you can do that i.e make text with different size in the same UILabel. See the NSLocalizedString for that and then do label.text = NSLocalizedString.

Comment: Hmm I'll probably end up going with this solution then

Comment: you can add attribute to String to make with smaller

Answer (score 0):

You can use autolayout to fix this problem.