# how to implement dynamic view

Tags: ios, swift3

Say I have 3 views, each view has a label in it. Now what I want is, based on the label content which will have different text size and length for different instances of a button click I want my view to fit label size.

if view is red colour, red colour should enclose the the text of label based on label height and width which changes every time..

class VerticalFitLayout: VerticalLayout {

```
override init(width: CGFloat) {
    super.init(width: width)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {

    var height: CGFloat = 0
    var zeroHeightView: UIView?

    for i in 0..<subviews.count {
        var view = subviews[i] as UIView
        height += yOffsets[i]
        if view.frame.height == 0 {
            zeroHeightView = view
        } else {
            height += view.frame.height
        }
    }

    if height < superview!.frame.height && zeroHeightView != nil {
        zeroHeightView!.frame.size.height = superview!.frame.height - height
    }

    super.layoutSubviews()

}
```

}

am I proceeding in the right direction?

see this image http://imageresize.org/Output/6e2d4598-355c-4c0c-ae9e-9ce0a4fad574.png
but what I want is one view which will change as per text. The label receives input from an array or a web service whatever..

Comment: you can use autolayout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340026/make-label-only-as-wide-as-it-needs-to-be/42340556#42340556

Comment: http://imageresize.org/Output/6e2d4598-355c-4c0c-ae9e-9ce0a4fad574.png.  this is how I want.. I want to resize view based on text length and I only have one view which will be receiving variable length text

Comment: Yes this is possible with autolayout.

Comment: its very simple to do with autolayout

Comment: Referring my image I showed, say if I have only white view and all the contents from black white and blue should be shown in white view only, one at a time based on a button click. This will require my white view to shape(height I meant) according to contents of UIlabel which gets content dynamically from say an array.. can this work with auto layout alone..? I am trying to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autolayout

Something like this, and UILabel number of lines set to 0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks,I understood what you meant, but say if I have only red view and all the contents from orange red and blue should be shown in red one, one at a time based on a button click. This will require my red view to shape(height I meant) according to contents of UIlabel which gets content dynamically from say a array.. can this work with auto layout alone..?

Comment: Do you want height of view to be changed dynamically at run time based on content? autolayout should take care of it.